# What’s the best way to pick up manga in Norfolk?

Tags: resources, england

I've loved anime for a while now and have recently started exploring manga. It's super expensive to buy, and I was wondering if there is anywhere I can pick some up cheap, or trade, or whatever. Also, libraries have been suggested; are there any libraries in Norfolk with decent manga selections?